# Laptop suddenly freezes and this text comes up

Tags: kernel, amdgpu

```
19:15:11 (uetoothd): Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
19:15:11 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02
19:15:11 (uetoothd): src/plugin.c:plugin_init() Failed to init bap plugin
19:15:11 kernel: amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: SECUREDISPLAY: query securedisplay TA failed. ret 0x0
19:15:11 kernel: amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: SECUREDISPLAY: query securedisplay TA failed. ret 0x0
19:15:11 kernel: amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: Secure display: Generic Failure.
```

Thinkpad E14 Gen 2
AMD Ryzen 5 4500U